# Why am I getting an blank character at the end of an element when randomly selecting an element from a word list

Tags: string, flutter, equality, compareto

I have to hard code my selectedWord to avoid the blank character

```
Future<String> getData() async {
    try {
      return await rootBundle.loadString('text_file/four_words.txt');
    } catch (e) {
      throw (e.toString());
    }
  }
Future<String> val = getData();
val.then((value) {
  setState(() {
    dataString = value;
    var elements = dataString.split("\n");
    elements.forEach((element) {
      wordList.add(element);
      //debugPrint(element);
    });


_selectNewWord() {
    setState(() {
      selectedWord = wordList[_random.nextInt(wordList.length)];
      selectedWord=selectedWord[0]+selectedWord[1]+selectedWord[2]+selectedWord[3];
      var elements2 = selectedWord.split("");
      myList.clear();
      for (var element in elements2) {
        if (element.isNotEmpty) {
          myList.add(element);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about problem you're observing, perhaps with examples?

Comment: You could try `dataString.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n").split("\n")` to make it work for both cases.

Comment: Is this problem actually reproducible with the code that you've shown, or is it dependent on the code you haven't shown that loads data from a text file?  If you're reading words from a text file, you would need to ensure that carriage return and/or linefeed characters have been removed.  Your `element.isNotEmpty` check will test only for an empty string (`''`), not for whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented dataString.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n").split("\n") and it solved the problem by removing the \r that was causing the extra item in the split list